# How do I set timeout to make a list of things animate in separately?

Tags: javascript

```
 window.addEventListener('scroll', (e) => {
    let scrollPos = window.pageYOffset;
     if(scrollPos > 1171){
         for(let i=0; i<artists.length; i++){
         artists[i].classList.add('showing');
         }
     }
   });
```

I know I should use set time out, i cannot get it to work for the life of me, any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Can you please add your fullcode so we can check what you want?

Comment: Your question and code seem to bear no relation.

Comment: Please provide proper description of your problem/solution you want to achieve.

Comment: Unless I'm totally off (and wasted 7 minutes answering the question), OP wants to stagger the animations of each `artists` element, instead of the `showing` class animating all `artists` elements simultaneously. I think the code and the title of the question together make it clear what OP is going for here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're using `let`, `i` will remain scoped to the `for` loop itself. This means a simple `setTimeout` will do. However, if you were using `var` 
for `i`, you would need to wrap the `setTimeout` call in a [closure](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Closures) to ensure `i` is scoped to your loop.

**Using `var` (old school)**

```
for (var i = 0; i < boxes.length; i++) {

  // We have to close over i because we have no block scope
  (function(index) {     
    setTimeout(function() {
      boxes[index].classList.add('showing')
    }, (index * 500)) // .5s, 1s, etc.     
  })(i)
}
```

**Using `let`**

```js
const boxes = document.querySelectorAll('.box');

for (let i = 0; i < boxes.length; i++) {
  // i is scoped to the block
  setTimeout(function() {
    boxes[i].classList.add("showing");
  }, i * 500); // .5s, 1s, etc.
}
```

```css
@keyframes fadein {
  to {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}

.box { 
  opacity: 0;
  background-color: red; 
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}

.box.showing { animation: 1s fadein linear forwards; }
```

```html
<div class="box"></div>
<div class="box"></div>
<div class="box"></div>
```

Comment: old school, jajajjaja